# Jquery menu, select just the next child depth

Tags: jquery, menu

example here http://www.brvr.net/menu

Hello,

finishing my menu, but with one problem.

On mouse over / leave  it works good, but on hover the 3rd level (nivel_3) is showed when hovering 1st level (novel_1), with should just show the 2nd level (nivel_2)

how can I solve this

```
$('.nivel_'+nivel+'').hover(
        function() { $(this).find('ul > li').css('display', 'block'); },
        function() { $(this).find('li').css('display', 'none'); }
    );
```

Thanks

Comment: I have cross-checked your source code. I can see that there is no 3rd level. Actually 2nd level text is showing as 3rd level. Since text length (2nd level text: **Filho do filho da nova pÃ¡gina**) is big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your HTML it's hard to be exact, but I expect you only want the `ul` that are direct children of the element being hovered.

```
$('.nivel_'+nivel+'').hover( 
    function() { $(this).find('> ul > li').css('display', 'block'); }, 
    function() { $(this).find('li').css('display', 'none'); } 
);
```